# Count data and split into two columns

Tags: php

I am tweaking a facebook album class that loops and echos data. The problem is that when it echos it loops into one column and I want to separate it into 2 columns. This is what it looks like now:

```
foreach($json->data as $v)
                    {
echo "<a class='ImageLink' rel='lightbox[photos]' href = '".$v->source."'><img style='margin:10px;' width='110px' src='".$v->picture."' /></a>";
                    }
```

I am trying to do something like so:

```
$count = count($json->data);
$half_count = $count/2;
             echo "<ul class='float:left;'>";
$counter = 0;
    foreach($json->data as $v)
                        {
        if ($counter == $half_count +1){echo "<ul class='float:left;'>";}
            echo "<li>". $v->picture  ."</li>";
        if ($counter == $half_count){ echo "</ul>";}

                        $counter++;
                        }
    echo "</ul>";
```

But when I use the count function on $json->data and echo that it gives me an array. Please help;

Comment: Do a `var_dump($count)`. That shouldn't be an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"But when I use the count function on $json->data and echo that it gives me an array." <- Count will always return an int.

Try the following correction to your code:

```
$count = count($json->data);
$half_count = ceil($count / 2); // make sure to ceil to an int. This will have your first column 1 larger than the second column when the count is odd
echo '<ul style="float:left">';
$counter = 0;
foreach($json->data as $v) {
    echo '<li>' , $v->picture , '</li>';
    $counter += 1;
    if ($counter == $half_count && $count != 1) {
        echo '</ul><ul style="float:right">';
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Thank you in my real script I had some many $counts that I forgot the count() but put it in my post. HAHA I need to start thinking of new variable. @Dimitry thanks for your help the ceil  was going to be next question.